Soap webservice returning Request format is invalid: text/xml
I have created a web service. Unfortunately, I am not well versed with SOAP call, however I don't think I am far off. The web service shown below has 3 test endpoints which I am able to call without any issue, however when I try to call InsertTx5xxCO2Sample, I am getting an error:

Request format is invalid: text/xml

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this one endpoint.
Web service: UserService.asmx:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

namespace SOAPWebServiceProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for UserService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://cometsystem.cz/schemas/soapTx5xxCO2.xsd")]
    [SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class UserService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetUserDetails(int userId)
        {
            // Example logic to fetch user details from a database
            if (userId == 1)
                return "User: John Doe, Email: john.doe@example.com";
            else
                return "User not found";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string TestExml(string testexl)
        {
            List<string> workingDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Split('\\').ToList();
            workingDir.RemoveAt(0);
            workingDir.RemoveAt(workingDir.Count - 1);
            string path = string.Join(@"\", workingDir);
            File.WriteAllText(path + @"\Test.txt", "Hello world");
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public bool InsertTx5xxCO2Sample(string passKey, string device,
                                         string temp, string relHum,
                                         string compQuant, string co2,
                                         string alarms, string lev1,
                                         string lev2, string lev3,
                                         string compType, string tempU,
                                         string timer)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("passKey: {0}", passKey));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("device: {0}", device));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("temp: {0}", temp));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("relHum: {0}", relHum));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("compQuant: {0}", compQuant));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("co2: {0}", co2));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("alarms: {0}", alarms));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("lev1: {0}", lev1));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("lev2: {0}", lev2));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("lev3: {0}", lev3));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("compType: {0}", compType));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("tempU: {0}", tempU));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("timer: {0}", timer));

            List<string> workingDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Split('\\').ToList();
            workingDir.RemoveAt(0);
            workingDir.RemoveAt(workingDir.Count - 1);

            string path = string.Join(@"\", workingDir);

            if (File.Exists(path + @"\Test2.txt"))
                File.Delete(path + @"\Test2.txt");

            File.WriteAllText(path + @"\Test2.txt", sb.ToString());

            return true;
        }
    }
}

Web service web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
      <webServices>
          <protocols>
              <add name="HttpGet"/>
              <add name="HttpPost"/>
          </protocols>
      </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.9.0" newVersion="5.2.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>

Call:
POST http://ipsum:5854/UserService.asmx/InsertTx5xxCO2Sample HTTP/1.1
Host: ipsum:5854
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 656

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<InsertTx5xxCO2Sample xmlns="http://cometsystem.cz/schemas/soapTx5xxCO2.xsd">
    <passKey>16963997</passKey>
    <device>4158</device>
    <temp>24.7</temp>
    <relHum>35.9</relHum>
    <compQuant>8.6</compQuant>
    <co2>510</co2>
    <alarms>hi,lo,no,no</alarms>
    <lev1>0</lev1>
    <lev2>0</lev2>
    <lev3>1</lev3>
    <compType>Dew point</compType>
    <tempU>C</tempU>
    <timer>10</timer>
</InsertTx5xxCO2Sample>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Response:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2024 18:34:24 GMT
Content-Length: 38

Request format is invalid: text/xml.

